# Get ip address of host name or Convert host name to ip address in php

Tags: php, ip, ip-address, lookup, hostname

I have a script that use api to get ip informations of an ip address. and i get a problem of getting ip address of a domain or hostname or convert it to ip, i'm looking for a code to resolve this problem, so when visitor come to website can tape or look for ip and also domain name and get ip of domain and relative information and thank you.

index.php

```
<?php

require_once('ipapi.class.php');

if(isset($_GET['ip']))
$rip = $_GET['ip'];
else
$rip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query

$query = IPAPI::query("$rip");

echo "\t IP Information: " .$rip. "<br />";
echo "\t ISP: " .$query->isp . "<br />";
echo "\t Organization: " .$query->org . "<br />";
echo "\t City: " .$query->city . "<br />";
echo "\t Region: " .$query->regionName . "<br />";
echo "\t Country: " .$query->country . "<br />"; 

?>

<form name="input" action="#" method="get">
IP: <input type="text" name="ip">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

ipapi.class.php

```
 if (getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") && strcasecmp(getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP"), "unknown")) 
 { 
    $rip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP"); 
 } 
 else if (getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") && strcasecmp(getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"), "unknown")) 
 { 
    $rip = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"); 
 } 
 else if (getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") && strcasecmp(getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"), "unknown")) 
 { 
    $rip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); 
 } 
 else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] &&       strcasecmp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "unknown")) 
 { 
    $rip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
    $rip = "unknown"; 
 }
```

PS : rip = ip i name it rip instead of ip

Comment: Look into `parse_url()`: http://us1.php.net/parse_url

Comment: i did but i didn't get it !! i'm newbie in php !! how it woks?

Comment: `$url = parse_url('http://'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); echo $url['host'];`

Comment: thank you, but where do i have to put this line ?? and how i use it ?

Comment: See http://us3.php.net/parse_url . Example #2 should help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use nslookup to resolve hostname to IP.

```
echo shell_exec('nslookup ' . $example_host_name);
```

Comment: thank you for fast reply, but how to put it inside and where exactly?? i'm just newbie in php, sorry for my english :P

Comment: just put the above line anywhere in your code, and it will output the IP address (assuming your $example_host_name variable is set to whatever host name you are trying t look up!).

Comment: i guess you didn't understand my problem, but thank you anyway